# Can connect, but no internet on Ubuntu 16.04, works fine on windows 10 (IPV4/IPV6 problem)

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4

I am having problems with my internet connection on Ubuntu 16.04. I can connect to the wireless network but i have no access to internet, 
In my laptop i also have windows 10 and it can connect and browse perfectly fine.
I noticed that i can ping IPv6 addresses but not IPv4:

output ping Google DNS

```
luka@luka-Inspiron-3458:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
173 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 173374ms
```

output ping6 Google DNS

```
luka@luka-Inspiron-3458:~$ ping6 2001:4860:4860::8888
PING 2001:4860:4860::8888(2001:4860:4860::8888) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=286 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=60.6 ms    
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=61.3 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=60.8 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=5 ttl=48 time=60.9 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=6 ttl=48 time=60.2 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=7 ttl=48 time=59.5 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=8 ttl=48 time=60.8 ms
^C
--- 2001:4860:4860::8888 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7010ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 59.573/88.846/286.406/74.672 ms
```

But it seems that i can't resolve any hostname with IPv6 (neither with IPv4)

trying to resolve hostname

```
luka@luka-Inspiron-3458:~$ ping6 google.com
unknown host

luka@luka-Inspiron-3458:~$ ping6 ipv6.google.com
unknown host

luka@luka-Inspiron-3458:~$ ping6 localhost
unknown host
```

I can normally ping localhost though

This is NOT a new install of Ubuntu, it happened when I try to connect in a new network (I am unable to test if i can connect to other networks rigth now)

EDIT:
output of cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
luka@luka-Inspiron-3458:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces 
 # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
```

output of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:47:47:29:b9:98
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11920 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0    
          TX packets:11920 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:778490 (778.4 KB)  TX bytes:778490 (778.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:6d:83:9b:1d:6f      
        inet addr:192.168.1.75  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0    
          inet6 addr: 2806:10a6:5:177c:b66d:83ff:fe9b:1d6f/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2806:10a6:5:177c:c61:441f:5f13:8edf/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::b66d:83ff:fe9b:1d6f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9990 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11766 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:586026 (586.0 KB)  TX bytes:1298218 (1.2 MB)
```

output iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"INFINITUM0368"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: E4:3E:D7:3B:1B:42   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:521   Missed beacon:0


eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Let me know if you need me to run any command.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It may be because you were set up with a static ip and the new network has different settings .. can you post the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: i don't remember setting a static ip, here is the output:



luka@luka-Inspiron-3458:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

 auto lo

 iface lo inet loopback

Comment: is this a graphical interface .. if so click the network icon at the bottom of the screen and see if you have an a selection near the top that says ifupdown (yourethernetname) ... if so .. click that and then see if you have access to the net.. actually .. is that all the cat said was what you posted here .. just `auto lo iface lo inet loopback` it didn't continue with `# The primary network interface`

Comment: i click on the network icon but i dont see the selection you mention

Comment: yes, that was all the cat command said

Comment: hmm sounds like maybe the network card isn't being seen or something .. can you edit your question and add the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` as well as the output of `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` this should help me and others see what the setup is and how its set up on your system

Comment: was trying to find a way to get you into the stack exchange chat  room so I could try to trouble shoot but since you only have 1 rep you wont be able to type there :( ... hmm do you have google hangouts?

Comment: :( any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up disabling IPv4 and using public DNS64 servers.
I'm going to leave the link to my post on another forum where this was solved

[Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1278597/i-can-ping-ipv6-but-not-ipv4?noredirect=1#comment1888081_1278597)